# How to change zsh shell to git shell on Mac OS?

Tags: git, gulp, zsh

guys!
I want to change zsh shell to git shell on Mac Os. Because I have a problem to launch gulp builder. =(
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etnsN.png)

Comment: I don't think "git shell" exists on mac os. Instead try using the command `gulp` without `run`.

Comment: Thank you!
I tried, but this command gulp moves me into another folder gulp..

Comment: Look at this screen please: https://ibb.co/cG2RN7

Comment: And this screenshot: https://ibb.co/edYu9n

Comment: It's because zsh is seeing the folder, so when you type `gulp` it moves you into that folder. Maybe change the folder name and try again?

Comment: Please also stop posting images and instead paste the code into the question.

Comment: Which directory is the `gulp` command actually in? Add that directory to your path, or use the path name for the command. `gulp` changing the the directory is a symptom of your actual problem (type `setopt noautocd`, then try running `gulp` again, to make that clearer.)

Comment: `zsh` usually only auto cds if the command can not be found. So I have to ask: Are you sure `gulp` is installed on your system?

Comment: I've found the solution how to fix this bug.
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `zsh` but the fact that you don't have `gulp` installed in a directory where the shell searches for it. No shell is able to find the executable `gulp` program because it is not in the `$PATH` environment variable.

#### Solution #1

If you are using `gulp` for only one project then you probably have it installed in the current project (run `npm list --depth=0` in the project directory to check). If this is the case, run it as:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/gulp
```

#### Solution #2

If you are using `gulp` for many projects it could be useful to install it globally, at the account level. For that, run the following command in any directory:

```
$ npm install -g gulp
```

Make sure you already have a `bin` directory in your home directory (create it using `mkdir -p ~/bin`) because this command creates a symlink to the `gulp` executable in it.

This symlink makes `gulp` available as a program to be executed from any directory.